# BLE CoreBluetooth throughput issues

Tags: swift, networking, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, throughput

I have implemented 2 ways of communication(via GATT and L2Cap) between central and peripheral.
In my case central is MacBook 2020 air m1 and peripheral is iPhone 11.

Methods for both ways:

1. Via GATT

Central:

Sending to peripheral

```
private func sendToPeripheralViaGATT() {
    
        guard let discoveredPeripheral = discoveredPeripheral,
                let transferSimpleCharacteristic = transferSimpleCharacteristic
            else { return }
        while sentBytes < outputStreamData.count {
                    
            let mtu = discoveredPeripheral.maximumWriteValueLength (for: .withResponse)
            
            let amountToSend = min(mtu, outputStreamData.count - sentBytes)
            let chunk = outputStreamData.subdata(in: sentBytes..<(sentBytes + amountToSend))
            discoveredPeripheral.writeValue(chunk, for: transferSimpleCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
            
            sentBytes += amountToSend
        }
        if(sentBytes >= outputStreamData.count){
            discoveredPeripheral.writeValue(
                "EOM".data(using: .utf8)!, for: transferSimpleCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)

            print("(CENTRAL) GATT sendining is ended. Time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())")
            sentBytes = 0
        }
    }
```

Reading from Peripheral

```
  func peripheral(
        _ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
        didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
        error: Error?
    ){
        if(characteristic.uuid == UuidsStore.chatTextUUID){
            guard let characteristicData = characteristic.value,
                let stringFromData = String(data: characteristicData, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
            if stringFromData == "EOM" {
                print("(CENTRAL) GATT reading is ended. Time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()), Bytes: \(inputStreamData.count)")
             }
            } else {
                inputStreamData.append(characteristicData)
            }
            
        }
    
    }
```

Peripheral:

Reading from central

```
func peripheralManager(
        _ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager,
        didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]
    ) {
        for request in requests
            {
            if request.characteristic.uuid.isEqual(UuidsStore.chatTextUUID)
                {
                guard let req_value = request.value,
                    let stringFromData = String(data: req_value, encoding: .utf8) else { continue }
                if stringFromData == "EOM" {
                        print("(PERIPHERAL) GATT reading is ended. Time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()), Bytes: \(inputStreamData.count)")
                    
                } else {
           
                    inputStreamData.append(req_value)
                    
                }
                }
            peripheralManager?.respond(to: request, withResult: CBATTError.success)
          }
    }
```

Sending to central

```
    func sendToCentralViaGATT() {
        guard !PeripheralViewController.EOMSent else { return }
        guard let transferCharacteristic = transferCharacteristic else {
            return
        }
        var didSend = true
        while sentBytes < outputStreamData.count && didSend {
                    
            let mtu = self.central!.maximumUpdateValueLength
            
            let amountToSend = min(mtu, outputStreamData.count - sentBytes)
            let chunk = outputStreamData.subdata(in: sentBytes..<(sentBytes + amountToSend))
            
            didSend = peripheralManager.updateValue(chunk, for: transferCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: nil)

            sentBytes += amountToSend
        }
        if(sentBytes >= outputStreamData.count){
            let didSentEOM = peripheralManager.updateValue("EOM".data(using: .utf8)!, for: transferCharacteristic, onSubscribedCentrals: nil)
            if didSentEOM{
                print("(PERIPHERAL) GATT sendining is ended. Time: \(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())")
                PeripheralViewController.EOMSent = true
                sentBytes = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

For L2Cap code is pretty similar , just like stream writing and stream reading.

And here some test benches with 1.1mb file that I'm sending from central to peripheral or vice versa.

GATT

Central to peripheral - 78 sec - 1.1mb

Peripheral to central - 35sec - 1.1mb

L2Cap

Central to peripheral - 37 sec - 1.1mb

Peripheral to central - 31 - 1.1mb

Throughput about - 14-33 kb/sec, looks like pretty small. In BLE specifications I saw 1 mb/sec at least for bluetooth 5.0.

I also tried to set desiredConnectinLatency(it makes things worse) or sending from central via .withoutresponse, but I don't know how to catch data on peripheral for this case.

Are there any ways to improve throughput in CoreBluetooth?

Comment: You receive write without response in the same way. The difference is that the central does not get any response to the write. If you use write without response the your central code needs to handle the error that will be returned when no more packets can be sent and resume sending when the peripheral is ready again. I would expect both of these methods to be much slower than L2Cap.

Comment: See https://github.com/paulw11/L2CapDemo/

Comment: @Paulw11 I saw your examples, thanks. Did you measure throughput of yours implementation? Because my benches say almost equal speed(I have the same implementation for L2Cap as yours)

Comment: Have you tried changeing the MTU size? If you change MTU size to a larger value; the data transfer in each frame will be larger hence can reduce the transfer time and increase the throughput.

Comment: @Kozmotronik I have maximum possible MTU size for now(it's around 500). I've tried to change it from 20 to max(without positive affects)

Comment: Hmm I see. May be you should consider using threading to process the arrived data and return from CoreBluetooth callbacks as soon as possible. Using queueing techniques along with a serial thread other than the CoreBluetooth's thread may improve the overall operation.

Comment: @Paulw11 didReceiveWrite hangs on 30392 bytes read. I used withoutResponse option.

Comment: I ran some tests on my L2Cap demo and I can write at about 16.7KB/sec - which is about 134Kbps - This was sending from my iPhone 13 to my M1 MacBook Pro

Comment: @Paulw11 I have around 31kb/sec which is - 248 kbps. I'm not sure that is max limit of throughput, don't you?

Comment: That sounds pretty fast for BLE.  It is not a high-speed transfer mechanism

Comment: @Paulw11 I read that BLE 5.0 at least, can reach 1 mbps(around 125 KB/s) that in 4 times faster that I reached((

Comment: @Paulw11 but here I've found something interesting https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android/

Comment: Looks like I have already reached maximum throughput...